# selenium ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I working on selenium and I face following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
```

Current browser version is `90.0.4430.212` with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I started receiving this error after a manual Chrome update, then my node app started to give me the exact message above about Chrome version 91.

After reading this thread and a few other things, I decided to run `npm outdated` with this result:

| Package | Current | Wanted | Latest | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chromedriver | 91.0.1 | 91.0.1 | 92.0.2 | selenium |

I modified my package.json chromedriver dependency to the 92.0.2 version and then ran: `npm update`, my node app now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As literally mentioned in the error, you are using incorrect version of ChromeDriver.
So, you have to download ChromeDriver version according to Chrome browser version you are using.

Comment: my current chrome version is 90.0.4430.24 and i also download chrome drive with same version  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/

Answer (score 0):

you are using beat version of chromdriver which is 90.0.4430.212, Not that it is not a stable driver. You can download `90.0` from the below link.

You need to have compatible version of selenium and chromedriver.

Download latest selenium web driver from here [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Download latest and compatible version of chromedriver from here [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

latest chromedriver version is `Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24` this is compatible with `Selenium 3.141.59`

Comment: how i check current version on selenium

Comment: which IDE you are using ? is it Pycharm ?

Comment: in pycharm you can directly go to files-> settings -> your project and then reference library. I am not sure about your IDE. But if you see reference library that is it.

Comment: Now i face this error NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined

Comment: Did the above issue get resolved ? `SessionNotCreatedException` ? Chrome is getting launched ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have downloaded the chromedriver that supports only Chrome version 91.
You can download the chromedriver best suited for your version [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/)

Comment: how to setup path of chrome driver

Comment: Add this to your code for setting up the path:

Comment: `PATH="./chromedriver.exe" #complete path of chromedriver                                                         
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)`

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it my manually setup path

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/automation/chromedriver")
```